# Linking two List Structures Together

Tags: java, list, hashmap, hash

I have a two lists. `List A` and `List B`.

Each element of list A has a list of elements from `List B`. I have populated the two lists but population of the List within the element of List A is still to be done.

They both have a property on which the linkage can be done; say

an element from List B; if has the field `1` as the id of the element from List A, then it gets added to that element from List A.

Now i am currently doing it using a for loop within another for loop. Somethign like this

```
for(each A)
{
for(each B)
{
if(fieldsmatch)
{
add B to the List of the element from A
}
}
```

Will it be better if I Hash all the elements from List A and then perform lookups while going through each element from List B.

Thanks.

Can i use HashMap for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reverse the logic. Create a hashmap from B that maps each id to a list of elements that have that id. Then  for each element of A, look up the list by id and assign it to the field in the A element.

```
Map<IdType, List<B>> map = new HashMap<IdType, List<B>>();
for(each b in B) {
    List<B> list = map.get(b.id);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<B>();
        map.put(b.id, list);
    }
    list.add(b);
}
for(each a in A) {
    a.b_list = map.get(a.id);
    // if you need an empty list instead of null:
    if (a.b_list == null) {
        a.b_list = new ArrayList<B>();
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you that, actually, a single element from a can have multiple elements from b, hence wont it be better if i hash all the elements from A, then for each b with the id, get element from A and add to list.
Cant do it this way, because it is a one to many relation and hence the b.id wont be unique; i.e. the id on which i am linking the two sets. But it will be unique for A.
Let me know if i am wrong.
And thanks for the response. :)

Comment: please tell what kind of objects are present in List A and List B?

Comment: @Kraken - It's just as you say -- each element from A can have multiple elements from B in a list. The first loop constructs the lists and the second loop attaches each list to the element(s) of A that have the corresponding id.

Comment: @Byter - I was using `A` as the type of element in "list A" and `B` as the type of element in "list B".

Comment: @TesHopp  okay, so wifor all the B elements, i get the list in the hashmap that have the same id, and then the element from A will get the List as a whole and not just the single element at a time.
Thanks. :)

Comment: @TedHopp what does the code `List<B> list = map.get(b.id); ` do? 
Assuming i have my lists with me, i wont need to do much in the `for(each b in B) { ` block, rather just `map.put(b.id, list); ` would be sufficient? right?

Comment: @Kraken - The first loop builds the lists; they don't exist (in final form) until the first loop finishes. Notice that each `b` is being stored in a list that is in the map. However, if `b.id` is a new value, never seen before, then there is no list corresponding to that id in the map, so you have to create it and add it to the map. That's what the `if (list == null) {...}` does. Once past the `if` block, it's guaranteed that `list` is already stored in the map under `b.id`, so all you need to do is add `b` to the list. It is only in the second loop that you have all the lists in hand.

Comment: @TedHopp I have Complete List of A and Complete List of B.With no link whatsoever between them. `Map<IdType, List<B>> map = new HashMap<IdType, List<B>>();` Creates a hash map, but it doesnt have anything in it yet, right? Then what do you expect `List<B> list = map.get(b.id);` to return? With no element in the map as yet? Now i come to